# In-App Purchases incomplete transactions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox, storekit

I have an app with In-App purchases and each time I try to make a purchase, the app keeps notifying me of old transactions which I failed to mark as finished. In particular, it gives me a dialog asking me for credentials of old test accounts, even if I have logged out of an account in the settings on the device. I tried using the following code to see if there are any incomplete transactions, but there are none:

```
NSArray *transactions = [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions];
    for(id transaction in transactions){
        NSLog(@"Clearing incomplete transactions...");
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
```

Is there a way to address this issue and make the prompts go away?

Comment: I am looking for the answer. Did you have any?